# How To Remove Icons No Longer Needed From The Applications Folder

Tags: applications, icons

How can I remove icons from the applications folder in Elementary OS6? I've tried AppEditor and nothing seems to be working.

Answer (score 0):

Application icon is stored in `/usr/share/applications/`, you can change or delete the icon you want.

Comment: How do I find that? I can’t locate that. Is it accessed through terminal? Please advise.

Comment: you can drag the application icon from the applications menu to the terminal to get the icon location, and add adelete command, like `sudo rm '/usr/share/applications/io.elementary.code.desktop'`

Comment: `sudo rm '/home/markvprzystawskisr/.local/share/applications/wine/Programs/iTunes/About iTunes.desktop'` try one by one

Comment: I appreciate the help. I guess it’s not a good idea to install Wine on Elementary OS with a Windows version of iTunes. It basically corrupted the whole computer and I ended up having to start from scratch. If the folks at Elementary say not to install something don’t!